# Does Google Navigation Live Traffic reroute during the journey?

Tags: google-maps-navigation

After setting a destination and start navigation and my journey, if a new incident occurs and slows/blocks the route, is Google Navigation able to update the route and find a faster alternative automatically before I get near?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the new Google Maps app we finally have this feature.
[From this post on the official Google blog](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/a-new-google-maps-app-for-smartphones.html):

> Enhanced navigation: In addition to current traffic conditions, we’ve added two new features to help you navigate around traffic. You can now see reports of problems on the road that you can tap to see incident details. While on the road, Google Maps will also alert you if a better route becomes available and reroute you to your destination faster. This feature is available only on Android and is coming soon to iOS.

From http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/maps/hL8UXVgRMcE/6PfnMZP8tIQJ

> Once you are in the "navigation" mode, you will see a status bar on the bottom that gives you an estimate of time remaining to your destination. The text of the time remaining changes color based on the traffic situation. The colors correspond to the former colored traffic light dot. If the words are red, that means there is some serious traffic on your route. Yellow indicates areas of slowed traffic. Green indicates that there are no anticipated delays.

Comment: Finally this feature has been added after so long.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know and based on my testings with the same concern, I came to the conclusion that it doesn't update the route based on traffic or any other reasons.

I even took an alternative route that I knew it was faster in rush hour conditions and the navigator was still trying to reroute me back to its original route, considering that faster due to speed limits.

Answer (score 5):

Google doesn't do this automatically, but you can ask it to do it.

In traffic view, there is a button in the lower right hand corner (looks like 2 diverging arrows (one dashed) both leading to a destination pin).

In turn by turn view, press **Menu** then **Routes and Alternatives**, and the same alternate routes button will show up second from the right.

However, Google Navigation will often not show you a route that avoids the traffic.  When that happens, start driving an alternate route and Google Navigation will eventually get the point, although you may have to listen to a lot of "turn around" alerts before it does.

Comment: The main issue with this that you have to know the alternative routes.

Comment: Well...yes and no.

I have been on 2 road trips where the google traffic turned red in front of me and I just got off at the next exit; after a mile or two google traffic snapped onto a new route that went around the traffic snarl.

Also, don't forget that google navigation has an embedded map which can help you figure out an alternate route, although this is most useful when travelling with a companion to act as navigator.  Otherwise, you should pull over 1st.

Most of all, google nav gives me the confidence to try stuff b/c I know that I can never get truly lost.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this post on the official Google blog, Navigation should have this feature](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2011/03/youve-got-better-things-to-do-than-wait.html) but like slybloty said I have never noticed any evidence of this happening

Comment: +1, thx for the link. It's available for *North America and Europe where both Navigation and real-time traffic data are available*. The example in the post is for NY, for which Google might have plenty of crowd sourced traffic data ready. Maybe there's a boundary for data *quality* and *quantity* at which this feature is enabled only. Mind: An areas cell coverage may also play a role how much good data google gets