# How can I ask the navigation for a fastest route (after traffic)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-navigation

I recently started a job on a long commute. The default route provided by Google Maps Navigation is always the same route. After some double length commutes, I started checking the alternate routes button. Sometimes one of those routes is faster. Is there any way I can get the app to give the the fastest route, taking traffic into account?

Comment: see http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25484/does-google-navigation-live-traffic-reroute-during-the-journey